# How to get custom field from Account on AfterUpdate trigger on Contact?

Tags: apex, trigger, account, contact

Is it possible to fetch custom Account fields when AfterUpdate on Contact runs?

Example:

```
trigger myTrigger on Contact(after update) {
   for(Contact cont : [select id, Account.My_Field__c 
                      from Contact 
                      Where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
       // this always returns null
       system.debug('account.my_field__c value: ' + cont.Account.My_Field__c);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a WHERE filter for the records in the trigger context

```
trigger myTrigger on Contact(after update) {
   for(Contact cont : [SELECT id, Account.My_Field__c 
                        FROM Contact
                        WHERE Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]) {
       // this always returns null
       system.debug('account.my_field__c value: ' + cont.Account.My_Field__c);
   }
}
```

Comment: i did add that and it still did not retrieve a value for `cont.Account.My_Field__c`. I am still getting null returned. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the contact's Account have a value for that lookup field?  Does the running user have FLS on that field?

Comment: double checked the FLS. I believe i may have found the core issue: when you query the way your code snippet is then I can fetch the field value as expected, but if I were to use `Trigger.newMap.values()` and say `cont.Account.My_Field__c` then I get an error. Through testing, I found the code snippet provided